# How to create create check point for "Flight Reservation" window in QTP 10.0

Tags: qtp, checkpoint

I am trying to insert an standard check point in my below script for last step / for Flight Reservation window.But when i trying to do so i am getting error message like that "cannot identify" window.

**My Script::**

```
    SystemUtil.Run("C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\QuickTest Professional\samples\flight\app\flight4a.exe")
Dialog("Login").WinEdit("Agent Name:").Set DataTable("userId", dtGlobalSheet)
Dialog("Login").WinEdit("Password:").Set DataTable("PassWord", dtGlobalSheet)
Dialog("Login").WinButton("OK").Click
Window("Flight Reservation").Close
```

[image: chkpoint add]
[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 1):

When creating a checkpoint QTP will try to get some properties from the application you're testing (`flight.exe` in this case) for this to work the application should be open.

The easiest way is to add the checkpoint while recording.

Answer (score 1):

Open the "Flight Reservation" application manually again & keep open in background and try right clicking on the Window("Flight Reservation").Close. Hope this time you can set the checkpoint.

Happy testing!

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck to the same point, Same error message, I just ran the application manually, and I was able to create a checkpoint, When QTP tries to create a checkpoint, it tries to fetch the properties, which it does not get when the application is not running, so make sure that application is running in the background.